# При выводе изображения появляется белый фон,

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Пытаюсь вывести изображение по маске (по его контуру), но никак не могу разобраться, почему непосредственно перед выводом изображения примерно на 1,5-2 секунды сперва появляется его контур (залитый белым), и только потом само изображение?

upd: если добавляю QThread::sleep(10); белый фон изображения соответственно висит 10 сек, затем прорисовывается картинка

Код и само изображение ниже:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QLabel win;
    QPixmap pix("res/pipe.png");
    win.setPixmap(pix);
    win.setMask(pix.mask());
    win.show();

    //QThread::sleep(10);

    return a.exec();
}
```

[image: Вот изображение]

Comment: А можете ту картинку pipe.png приложить в вопрос? Кнопка `править` кнопка Изображение

Comment: @gil9red добавил,

Comment: А если закомментировать `win.setMask(pix.mask());` картинка будет показана? У меня сработала маска, правда я на питоне проверял, но там тоже Qt5

Comment: @gil9red Да, но картинка будет уже в окне, а не обрезанная по контуру. Кстати, эта задержка с белым экраном все равно есть, и сейчас при закомментированной строке win.setMask(pix.mask());

Comment: А с `win.setMask(pix.mask());` окно пропадает и вместо него будет так картинка? Но задержка остается? Картинка у вас большая? Или может дело в скорости чтения с диска?

Comment: @gil9red да. и задержка остается. картинка не большая 256x256x32 (40kB). задержка из-за диска - сильно сомневаюсь, ведь диск SSD. Для чистоты эксперемента добавил задержку слип на 10 сек, и белый экран висит 10 сек.  QThread::sleep(10);

Comment: Не знаю в чем проблема тут, это может быть: в ОС, в оконном менеджере, в драйверах, в версии Qt, и т.п.. Кст, насчет sleep'а, Qt программы работают с циклом обработки событий, который создает QApplication и начинается с `exec()`, возможно в рамках этого цикла и делается вся работа с маской, поэтому пока цикл не запустился, виджет с маской работу не закончил. Кроме того, эта фигня с маской явно вместо с оконным менеджером выполняется

Comment: Чтобы проверить, точно ли не в диске проблема - засуньте картинку в ресуры. Я на своей машине попробовал - и так, и так нет задержек.

Comment: @Krepver странные вещи происходят. через ресурсы изображение вообще не показывает. пустой виджет. при том, что сам файл ресурсов и создавал, и добавлял само изображение через GUI-интерфейс в Qt-Creator, т.е., ошибок не должно быть. да и просто в коде навожу на ":/pipe.png" - и изображение тут же высвечивается. а вот при запуске программы - пусто, изображение вообще пропало, пустое окно. в общем, пойду разбираться в чем дело,